# House rule for calculating attack and damage in one roll

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, homebrew-review, attack-roll

I played many different RP systems and prefer faster and more narrative games. I have a new group I DM and we play D&D, because I love the lore. For combat do I use theater of mind combat with abstract battle zones and this works perfectly and I play now with the thought of reducing the attack action to one roll and would highly appreciate your feedback about the implications of the house-rule.

### Motivation

1. Have one roll for attack and damage.
2. Better hits do more damage

#### DM preparation

For Monster AC I add two more AC values. One with +2 and One with +9.

For PC weapons I calculate the min, average, max damage for each attack. This represents the quality of the hit and is connected to the three AC thresholds.

#### During Combat

Player rolls attack and checks which of the three AC threshold he passes. You pass the AC and do min damage, you pass the +2 AC threshold you do average damage, you pass the +9 AC threshold, you do max damage.

#### Math

In 5e the chance of hitting is on average 65%.
Based on that a +2 mod on AC reduces the chance to 55%.
And a +9 mod to AC reduces the chance to hit to 20%.

The three brackets represent you have a 65% chance to do minimum damage, 55% to do average damage and 20% to do max damage.

If you calculate the average distribution for this simplified damage distribution ä, you end up at the same average as rolling the damage dice. The three brackets for damage are a reduced damage distribution of the damage roll.

The difference is, a better it is directly higher damage. A stronger character has then a higher chance to do max damage on a weaker monster.

Comment: Welcome to the stack Christoph_Kralj!  Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) when you have a moment, and feel free to peruse the [help](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) center for more in-depth info about the site.

Comment: You can do something similar by rolling both dice at the same time without all of the mental gymnastics.  Know your weapon damage dice and roll that along with the d20; on a miss the dice are ignored.  Request for clarification: did you construct a table for your players to consult or is all of this done with mental calculations?  Lastly: don't use code block, use actual quotes or parens. Code blocks mess up screen readers.

Comment: What are the damage brackets based on?

Comment: Despite my effort, I wasn't able to imagine how it works. Maybe some tables and example of actual use in play would make it easier to understand? As for the last sentence, please avoid open ended "What do you think about this?" and similar. Questions where every answer is equally valid are forbidden, see help center. Ask a question in a way that would allow objective vote up or down on answers, not based purely in voters opinion, but on the answer merit and how good it answers the question asked.

Comment: Also, [ask] and [answer] provide some more guidance on how this SE site works.  And welcome. 

Comment: If you won't describe how are you making damage calculations, it'll be impossible to evaluate your system. Thus, still needs details.